# Could I use "This fits" with this meaning?

Tags: grammar, meaning

I would like to know if I could use "This fits" with the meaning of "It wasn't the best option, but it's ok, it'll work"

Example:

Person 1:

> Hey! Is there an air conditioner here?

Person 2:

> No. But there's a fan.

Person 1:

> This fits!

Comment: The first line should probably be given as a question: "Is there an air conditioner here?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, I've never heard "this fits" used that way.

**"That will do"** or, more commonly **"That'll do"** has that connotation that you're looking for--something is acceptable, but not ideal. You can also say "It'll do."

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/that%27ll_do